# Post filter on the basis of tags in django taggit(package)

Tags: django

I just installed django taggit by following official documentation. Every things work fine but when i click on the tags it doesn't filter post containing that tags here is my code.
Code containing models.py file

```
..............
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
..................
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = ((DRAFT, _('draft')),
                      (PUBLISHED, _('published')))
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), verbose_name=_(
        "Author"), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    title = models.CharField(_("Title"), max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(_("Slug"), unique_for_date='publish')
    status = models.IntegerField(
        _('status'), db_index=True,
        choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=DRAFT)
    tags = TaggableManager()



    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("blog:post_detail", kwargs={
            "pk": self.pk
        })
```

code contain views.py file

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    queryset = Post.published.all().order_by('-publish')
    context_object_name = 'post_list'
    template_name = "client/pages/blog_list.html"
    paginate_by = 7
```

urls.py file

```
from .views import PostListView,
..........
    path('tag/<slug:tag_slug>/', PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list_by_tag'),
..........
```

and in the templates file

```
<ul class="tags-inline">
                <li>Tags:</li>
                {% for tag in post_detail.tags.all %}
                <li>
                  <a href="{% url 'blog:post_list_by_tag' tag.slug %}">{{ tag.name }}</a>
                  ,
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your queryset to filter based on the tag.  This is bringing back everything based on `all()`

```
queryset = Post.published.all().order_by('-publish')
```

I'm not sure how you filter on Taggit